# Each statement in handlebarjs not working

Tags: ember.js

I am trying example tutorials for emberjs www.toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/03/02/emberjs-rc1-introduction-screencast/  here is my code in codepen www.codepen.io/rigeldeshmukh/pen/IgwvA  session template should print first as second

Answer (score 0):

You had `DS.attr('String')` instead of `DS.attr('string')` in your model and [Ember didn't like it](https://www.google.com/search?q=mad+hamster&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=xe6DUcKhO9DsigLx8YDgBA&biw=1295&bih=619&sei=yO6DUbLVEoqPiALt1ICgCQ#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sad+hamster&oq=sad+hamster&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5.3107.3305.0.3447.3.3.0.0.0.0.116.250.1j2.3.0...0.0...1c.1.12.img.qGTL59PvueQ&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.cGE&fp=c8e6beed76e6f964&biw=1295&bih=619).

Here's the corrected codepen :)

http://www.cdpn.io/hmApC

Comment: :) No worries. Been there.